# Can someone explain the functionality of ActiveRecord postgres pg_type?

Tags: postgresql, activerecord

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb

Can anyone explain regarding pg_type in Postgres? As I cannot find types in other database connection adaptors like MySQL and SQLite, what is its functionality and features it provides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL has a rich set of [native data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html) available to users.

Users can add new types to PostgreSQL using the [CREATE TYPE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html) command or new domains using [CREATE DOMAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html).

Also, when you create a table or a view, the corresponding composite type with the same name is automatically created.

Each database may have a different set of defined types. Information of all types and domains known in a database is stored in the [system catalog `pg_type`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-type.html)

Answer (score 2):

The postgres catalog table `pg_type` contains information about all data types available in your database. That includes built-in datatypes like `bool` and `text`, extension datatypes like `hstore`, and custom datatypes that are the result of using [`CREATE TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html).

There's more information available in [the postgres documentation for that table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-type.html), if you're interested. For most uses of the database, you don't need to access `pg_type`, but it can be useful. In this case, ActiveRecord is, among other things, querying `pg_type` to pull accurate information about the types of each column in a user-created table.